# Finding averages in Database Schema relationships

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the database schema with the following relations

```
Employee (eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:real)
Works (eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)
Department(did:integer, dname:string, budget:real, managerid:integer)
```

My goal is to find the average salary for all the emplyees that work for each given manager (listed in the output by eid). I tried the following schema 
but I believe I'm not grouping them correctly since I'm not recieving any data from the schema

```
SELECT D.managerid,  AVG(E.salary)
FROM Employee E, Department D, Works W
WHERE E.eid=W.eid AND W.did = D.did
group by D.managerid
```

How would I go about amending my sql statements. (Running on an Oracle Server)

Comment: When debugging queries, it's helpful to remove the aggregate functions (avg) and see if you can return the raw data for a single scenario.  In this case a single manager.  The where clause looks correct and should generate the same records as using join clauses.